# Can this be considered to be self-defense under U.S. laws (graphic video)?

Tags: united-states, self-defense

The video is graphic.

The store owner stabs a robber multiple times when his life wasn't threatened. Can this open him to criminal and civil lawsuits?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RCu4G_ZkBI0

I don't think this can be construed as self-defense, because his life wasn't threatened at all.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-defense_(United_States)

> In the U.S., the general rule is that "[a] person is privileged to use
> such force as reasonably appears necessary to defend him or herself
> against an apparent threat of unlawful and immediate violence from
> another."[1] In cases involving non-deadly force, this means that the
> person must reasonably believe that their use of force was necessary
> to prevent imminent, unlawful physical harm.[2] When the use of deadly
> force is involved in a self-defense claim, the person must also
> reasonably believe that their use of deadly force **is immediately
> necessary to prevent the other's infliction of great bodily harm or
> death.[3]** Most states no longer require a person to retreat before
> using deadly force. In the minority of jurisdictions which do require
> retreat, there is no obligation to retreat when it is unsafe to do so
> or when one is inside one's own home.[4]

They were stealing stuffs, so his life wasn't threatened.

Comment: Wheres is that quote from?

Comment: It depends on the state and the general rule can only be general. One other common rule is that certain offences (often murder, rape, kidnapping and robbery) are considered inherently so violent and dangerous that they always imply a substantial risk to life and deadly force is always justified. This can exist even in jurisdictions that normally require substantial proportionality or duty to retreat.

Comment: "They were stealing stuffs, so his life wasn't threatened." It is no longer just stealing if force is used or a potential use of force is reasonable perceived by the victim.

Comment: When you are wearing a mask and jump the counter you become a threat.